# Javascript show timer & after time ends it should get hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a countdown plugin from [Gieson](http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/countdown/)

and am trying to show the counter for a particular time & then after the time ends it should get hidden

My timer code

```
var myCountdown2 = new Countdown({
    time: 300, 
    width:200, 
    height:80, 
    rangeHi:"minute" // <- no comma on last item!
});
```

How do I add additional code to hide the counter after the counter reaches 0?

Comment: I updated your question to have enough information to be useful

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation at [this page](http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/countdown/)
just do

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/j6wTs/)

```
<div id="counter">
<script>

var myCountdown2 = new Countdown({
    time: 300, 
    width:200, 
    height:80, 
    rangeHi:"minute", 
    onComplete: function () {
      $("#counter").slideToggle();        
    }
});
</script>
</div>
```

or if you want to show a message for a little while and then hide the message

```
  onComplete: function() {
    $("#message").show();
    setTimeout(function() { $("#message").hide(); },3000);
  }
```

Comment: Well I can't so I won't - I'm on my phone so patience. I normally charge per hour so be happy

Comment: See update. One advice: SO participants do not like "Gimme the code" type of questions. Next time explain more and give more details, for example I had to find the countdown script you were talking about myself and create a jsFiddle.net - next time you do that before asking, OK?